# Which taxonomy or grouping name to use?

Tags: interface, wording, taxonomy

Working on an IoT interface, we have a section where users will edit projects. The current editing page is very long and has a lot of information, most of it clearly does not belong to the same hierarchy, so we have to "clean it".

Our problem is with the last part of the page, where users can add information and files for projects. At this moment they use a system of tabs with the following tabs:

- Project notes
- Project files
- Project Tasks
- Project time and equipment
- Township Range Section

and within those tabs, there are elements for interacting or displaying information.

We want to make a subpage for this section, but we are not sure what taxonomy to use for these tabs so they are easily understandable to any user. I was leaning toward **Assets** (or **Project Assets**), someone suggested **Project Information** or **Miscellaneous**, but I'm really not sure.

Of course we can test this later, but we need to have a good taxonomy to officiate as a page name so that users can see this subpage and understand what it is about (just in case, it would go right under the "Edit Project" page, so I think it helps to provide some context)

**Anyway, is any of these options correct? Or is there something better to describe or group these tabs?**

Answer (score 1):

**Assets** sounds the most familiar. There is no *correct* option though, it is mostly a matter of the already used language, the context and probably also taste.

Others could be **Properties**, **Objects** or **Attachments**.

But words like information and miscellaneous should difinitely be avoided. Everything is information and miscellaneous sounds unimportant and ignore-worthy.